# Using the correct MotionEvent for custom buttons

Tags: java, android, button, custom-controls, motionevent

I m making an app and i want to use custom button skins . The code i use for changing background when the button is pressed is the following :

```
 button3.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_buttonn);
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_buttonn);
            }else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_HOVER_MOVE) {
                button3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black_buttonn);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

This code is supposed to make a button blue when its being pressed and return it to black when released. It works but if you click the button and drag away from it the event ACTION_UP is not triggered . What event should i use in this case ?

I edited my code adding the event HOVER_MOVE which works when you move the finger out of the button.
But because these buttons are inside an item of a custom list view if you move the finger outside of the current item the event HOVER_MOVE is not triggered.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">  

<item     android:state_enabled="false"     
android:drawable="@drawable/default_bgnd" />

<item     android:state_focused="true"        
android:drawable="@drawable/new_green" />

<item     android:state_pressed="true"        
android:drawable="@drawable/new_green" />

<item     android:state_checked="true"        
android:drawable="@drawable/new_green"/>

<item     android:state_selected="true"        
android:drawable="@drawable/new_green" /> 
</selector>
```

Place this xml in drawables folder and Set this as the Backgroud to your button in xml
Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

Try returning `true` instead of `false`. `True` indicates that listener consumed the `TouchEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
onButton.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
if(ParentalSet.equalsIgnoreCase("OFF")){
switch (event.getAction()) {
case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
((TextView) v).setTextColor(0xFF000000);
onButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(buttonGlow));
break;
case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
onButton.setTextColor(Color.parseColor                                                                 (OptimumConstants.CODE_000000));
onButton.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable                                           (R.drawable.new_off));
break;
default:
break;
 }
}
return false;
}
});
```